# high-dimensional Spatial-temporal clustering

Tags: gis, cluster-analysis, wavelet, temporal

My question is, how I can make a cluster analysis from spatial - temporal and high dimensional data? my purpose is to find subspace clusters that can show patterns in the space and  in the time. over here space mean a geographic position, so I should use autocorrelation law (also knowns like Tobler law or the first law from geography).
is this right?, first I make a transformation from time to frequency through Wavelets transform from every variable (because all variables have time and geographic position related) and after that, taking that coefficients and applying one subspace clustering algorithm for  temporal high-dimensional clustering. once I have the temporal clusters I try to find a spatial "cluster" trough regionalization between temporal clusters.

Thanks in Advance any light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you use the toblers law as an interpretation of the spatial correlation (regionalization). Its not clear what the final application would be but, a few verification steps i would do in such circumstances would be: to check if the all(150) variables are all corresponding to the same scale in space and time, affected by the same kind of autocorrelation (stationarity) which can simplify the problems in few cases. And finally  also has to understand what features or patterns are to be extracted and how they are characterized. Check this out: http://www.geokernels.org/pages/modern_indexpag.html

Hope it helped !

Cheers
Ravi

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear what you would like to achieve here. In general for spatio temporal clustering one could use a distribution based model like a multivariate Guassian Mixture Model for a given patch in the Dataset, and update the covariance matrice parameters (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) - In case of the Wavelet transform coefficient clustering we ignore any spatial correlation to exist.

I am not sure by what you mean here by "regionalization"

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Ravi. well what I am trying to do is a characterization from spatial and temporal patterns in a special database where every row give information about the time when a measure is taken (measures about 150 different variables) and the geographic position.

Comment: one reason by not use the model that you proposed is that I wanna make a non-parametrical analysis from data. another reason is that this don't make special assumptions about Tobler's first law of geography.

Comment: Precisely regionalization is a way to make assumptioms about the Tobler's Law.

Comment: in this book one can find a explanation about [regionalization](http://books.google.com.co/books/about/Regionalization_of_watersheds.html?id=5oRSBgsSqrIC&redir_esc=y).

Answer (score 0):

You could treat time as just another dimension, depending on your application.

Comment: ,thank you. well about what I read, is necesary apply a temporal representation scheme like wavelet coeficients because in another way is just one non-temporal clustering method. i read that from this book [link](http://www.amazon.com/Temporal-Mining-Chapman-Knowledge-Discovery/dp/1420089765)

Answer (score 0):

What about constructing a temporal cluster data with a correlation coefficient against cluster which gives a variance equal to 1. A spatial cluster will be a scatter plot which obviously might derive from lognormal, skewed and regression plots.

Comment: Better avoid the impression of asking a question instead of trying to answer.

Comment: The moment generating function can describe the position of the sub space cluster. The standard covariate; Cov X^r,

Comment: Sum of X * sum of Y - (n population mean, neu)^r.  Cov (XY)^r , Y(X^r) = MX + C. Hence, Y(X^r) = Sum (MX + MY )+ Cutree (1-x) C [(n population mean, neu)^r] is the distribution.

Comment: I see that you insist on the question-like phrasing. You also give additional information inside comments instead of within the answer post. If you think so.... But maybe you have a look at [answer], with info on how to make answers with higher chances of being perceived as helpful. Good luck.